# Overlay with exact same size and position as image underneath it

Tags: css, vuejs3, aspect-ratio, nuxt3

I have an image in a nuxt template. I'd like the overlay to exactly have the size and position of the image. I dont know the aspect ration of the image in advance.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <img class="img" :src="image?.imageSrc" :alt="image?.id" />
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { Image } from "~/types/interfaces/image";

defineProps({
  image: {
    type: Object as () => Image | undefined,
    default: () => ({}) as Image,
  },
});
</script>

<style scoped lang="scss">
.overlay {
  background-color: green;
}

.img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add a class name in the parent div of `img class` and `overlay class`.

```
<template>
    <div class="box">
        <div class="overlay"></div>
        <img class="img" :src="image?.imageSrc" :alt="image?.id" />
    </div>
</template>
```

Add `CSS` for `box div` and `overlay div` like below,

```
.box {
    position: relative;
}
.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: green;
    opacity: 0.7;
}

.img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

You will see the green color overlay with the size of image. You can also use custom size of image by changing the size of `box div`

Image:
[image]

Comment: thank you @miltonbhowmick. It does not work as excpected: the overlay uses the complete available space, while the image only uses the maximal space it can cover without getting distorted (that means for an image in portrait format the overlay is wider).